# Load HTML elements one after the other

Tags: html

I have four HTML elements:

```
<img>
<img>
<p></p>
<input>
```

Currently, they load roughly in order from bottom to top (the bottom two load first) and this creates a disturbing effect where the input and text loads near the top and the traverses down the page as the images pop in.

I'd like for each element to load only after the one above has loaded. What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: *"Currently, they load roughly in order bottom to top"* no, from top to bottom. However, images are loaded asynchronously

Comment: yeah, always top to bottom. Try make your images smaller. Use tinypng or similar. Either that or load everything via javascript and use a $(document).ready function (Not the best suggestion but should do the trick?)

Comment: How about you reserve the space for the images?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can. I think you could only do something along the lines of adding a height and width to the images, so the space is accounted for as the images load.

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting a `width` or `height` property on the images

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3193889/pexels-photo-3193889.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-mati-mango-3193889.jpg&fm=jpg" width="100">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3193889/pexels-photo-3193889.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-mati-mango-3193889.jpg&fm=jpg" width="100">
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
<input>
```